# How to cut string size in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I want to save multiple string values in **one cookie**, with strings that are larger than 4kb cut to 1.3kb

This is my code - **notice** - im not sure code is working correctly, since no cookies show when i try to display them in textboxes, not sure why.

**EDIT** - **save cookies**

```
protected void btnCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
        cookie.Values.Add("cookie1", txtValue1.Text);
        cookie.Values.Add("cookie2", txtValue2.Text);
        cookie.Values.Add("cookie3", txtValue3.Text);

        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Write("Success!");
    }
```

**read cookies**

```
protected void btnLoadCookies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null))
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Request.Cookies["cookie"]["cookie1"];
            TextBox2.Text = Request.Cookies["cookie"]["cookie2"];
            TextBox3.Text = Request.Cookies["cookie"]["cookie3"];
        }
    }
```

Can you guys please help me create a function/code that would cut string size from 4kb to 1.3kb ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're not sure if your code is currently working, how can you know the size of the cookies?

Comment: What did you try? Did you happen to notice if `String` had any methods? Did you read any of their names? Did you try to call any of them?

Comment: i don't...i'm fairly new to this and i have no idea why cookies don't show up @MarkC.

Comment: Did you google [how to set cookies in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: i tried entering data in one category of textboxes and displaying it in another, but it doesn't seem to be working @EdPlunkett

Comment: i did, that's where i got part of the code @EdPlunkett

Comment: Are you showing all of the code you used to add the cookie?

Comment: yes indeed. @EdPlunkett

Comment: Please [read the examples on this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and see if you notice anything missing from your code where you try to add a cookie.

Comment: expiration? if you're poitning at "Response.Cookies.Add", i had i mind that   "cookie.Values.Add" would work as well @EdPlunkett

Comment: Why did you think that adding a value to a cookie would be the same as adding the cookie to Response? If you add a package of hotdogs to a bag of groceries, is that the same as putting the bag of groceries in your car?

Comment: This advice will serve you well for many years: When you copy example code, *don't change it until you have it working*.

Comment: fair enough, works now @EdPlunkett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't [adding the cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
    cookie.Values.Add("cookie1", txtValue1.Text);
    cookie.Values.Add("cookie2", txtValue2.Text);
    cookie.Values.Add("cookie3", txtValue3.Text);

    //  Now tell the Response about it
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Sorry to be such a royal pain in comments, but you ended up basically figuring it out yourself.

If you do end up needing to truncate the text, you want [`String.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx). But you can also give yourself more breathing room by saving three 4k chunks of text in three different cookies rather than three properties of one cookie.

Comment: no worries mate, that's how you learn. i know im a newb, but i always try to google it first before posting here. been working 2 jobs recently + uni, my brains just not working anymore...and yeh i'd agree, but im just following assignment instructions